# MySQL data to PDF PHP conversion error?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I want to export MySQL data to PDF but the time I click download this error occur:

> FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

this is my main code

```
<form class="Search_Form" action="moduleindex.php" method="POST">
<font class="Teacher_Label">Teacher Name:</font> <input class="Teacher_Search" type="text" name="TeacherName" value=""></input>
<font class="Section_Label">Section Name:</font> <input class="Section_Search" type="text" name="SectionName"></input>
<input class="Button_Search" name="Search_Record" type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
<form action="generate-pdf.php" method="POST">
<input class="Button_Pdf" name="Convert_Pdf" type="submit" value="Generate PDF"/>
</form>
```

this is part of the fpdf file that contains the error message

```
function _checkoutput()
{
  if(PHP_SAPI!='cli')
   {
   if(headers_sent($file,$line))
     $this->Error("Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at $file:$line)");
   }
  if(ob_get_length())
  {
         // The output buffer is not empty
         if(preg_match('/^(\xEF\xBB\xBF)?\s*$/',ob_get_contents()))
        {
        // It contains only a UTF-8 BOM and/or whitespace, let's clean it
        ob_clean();
        }
  else
      $this->Error("Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file");
   }
}
```

Comment: The solution..... don't send any output whatsoever to the browser before your PDF, no echo or print statements in your code, nothing outside of `?>` `<?php` tags, nothing

Comment: @MarkBaker but our teacher told me to put a preview on what are the data's to be downloaded so the user can check if it's right or wrong...

Comment: You can't send both html markup and a pdf file in the same request: one or the other, but not both.... that's the nature of http

Comment: @MarkBaker so sir if it's ok with you if i can send my file to your email so you could check it, it will be very great with me...it's like you save half of my future...

Comment: No, I don't respond to emails. You need to ensure that the download script called when you click on the submit button generates no additional output beyond the pdf file